# monaco-editor in React using TypeScript -> cannot find module 'monaco-editor'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack-dev-server, monaco-editor

I have been trying to integrate **monaco-editor** in a React app. I have had success but still facing issues. Below I have provided details of my development setup.

I have **tsconfig.json** file configured like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "lib": ["dom", "es5", "es2015.collection", "es2015.promise", "dom.iterable"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./node_modules",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "allowJs": true,
    
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,

    "preserveConstEnums": true,    
    "isolatedModules": true
  },

  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]  
}
```

And my package.json has the scripts configured like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "webpack serve",
    "server": "nodemon --exec ts-node server.tsx",
    "build": "webpack -w --mode=development"
  }
```

The *start* script is using **webpack-dev-server** and the server is using **ts-node** to run my *server.tsx* file.

The **monaco-editor** is imported in a React component *.tsx* file as `import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor';`

When I run this command: `npm run start` which uses **webpack-dev-server** all done nicely and I am able to see my app in the browser.

However, when I run this command: `npm run server` which uses **ts-node** to execute *server.tsx* file, I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'monaco-editor'
Require stack:
- D:\Development\Workstation\VividCodes.UI_OLD\src\components\TestMonaco.tsx
- D:\Development\Workstation\VividCodes.UI_OLD\src\components\App.tsx       
- D:\Development\Workstation\VividCodes.UI_OLD\server.tsx
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
```

This is a copy of the content of *server.tsx* file:

```
import express from 'express';
import * as React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

import App from './src/components/App';

const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const config = require('./webpack.config.js');

const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');

const server = express();
const compiler = webpack(config);
const port = 3000;

server.use(
  webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  })
);

server.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));

server.get('/', (req: any, res: any) => {
  const initialMarkup = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />);  
  console.log(initialMarkup);

  res.send(`
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Monaco_Editor</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="mountNode">${initialMarkup}</div>
        <script src="/app.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="/editor.worker.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="/json.worker.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="/css.worker.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="/html.worker.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="/ts.worker.bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `)
});

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port: ${port}`));
```

My plan was to use a correct custom server to render my components dynamically, than doing so on client-side.

Comment: You have to install the types for Monaco-editor I think. Try to install react-monitor-editor, it has its own types declarations

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Reluctant to use another third-party library. react-monaco-editor looks like someone's personal project and I am not sure it's a good idea for production.

Comment: How can I install the types for monaco-editor, without using someone else's library?

Comment: So you can install the types definition from microsoft but it is noticed that the react-monaco-editor has its own type declaration. See there : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-monaco-editor

Comment: Yes I know react-monaco-editor has its own type declaration, as per your advice. I am not a fan of that library to be fair. I need to figure out how I can resolve the issue related 'types', you have advised earlier without using any other libraries. Relying on personal projects for production is not a good practice.

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of the typings file, after all it works well with `npm run start`. I suspect that the monaco-editor dependency is not packaged for the use with `npm run server` (like webpack would do).

Comment: Thanks for your comment Mike, I have spent some time trying to figure this out. Yes, it is not to do with the typings, instead it doesn't render/package everything correctly. Something is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Monaco-editor** does not support server-side rendering. It cannot rebind to the existing DOM node. It has to be done on client-side unfortunately. And, there is currently no plans on implementing the server-side rendering functionality.

However, for those who have the same concern, if **Webpack** is what you're using for bundling, make sure you set minimising option to 'true'. This way, your bundled JS files will be much smaller. Also, there is a 'min' version of **monaco-editor** which can be used for production; but it's based on **AMD**.